# SAPUI5 Form Add Label and Input dynamically and set ID for Input but not function

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I am creating an application enable user to dynamically add new label and input into form. But I have set the new input id and enabled is false dynamically added by user. But when I click edit button, enabled set to true. It does not work. My application cant read the input id that I added dynamically in form.

The following is my sample code.

Add new label and input into my current form

```
        var _oSF2 = this.getView().byId("Extension_Form");
        _oSF2.addContent(new sap.m.Label({
                text: "Classification"
            }));
        _oSF2.addContent(new sap.m.Input({
                  id : "idExtensionInput1",
                  text : "text",
                  enabled: false
            }));
```

Set enablement for new input to true

```
    handleEditPress: function () {
        this.getView().byId("idExtensionInput1").setEnabled(true);

    }
```

Comment: did you look if your control has the ID via F12 Elements Tab?

Comment: Yes, it have ID with "idExtensionInput1-inner"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've added the input to no view. In your case, you can only access the input with `sap.ui.getCore().byId("idExtensionInput1")` but the correct way is to use `this.getView().createId()` and add it to the right view.

```js
    var _oSF2 = this.getView().byId("Extension_Form");
    _oSF2.addContent(new sap.m.Label({
            text: "Classification"
    }));
    <!-- language: lang-js -->

    _oSF2.addContent(new sap.m.Input({
        id : this.getView().createId("idExtensionInput1"), //Use createId() for this.getView()
        text : "text",
        enabled: false
    }));

    handleEditPress: function () {
       this.getView().byId("idExtensionInput1").setEnabled(true);
    }
```

One comment:
The first parameter for new sap.m.Input is the id. Please write:

```js
       _oSF2.addContent(new sap.m.Input(this.getView().createId("idExtensionInput1"), {
            text : "text",
            enabled: false
        }));
```

Comment: It does not work for me also. It return following error also "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setEnabled' of undefined"

Comment: Also with `sap.ui.getCore().byId()`?

Comment: It does not work also. Seems like it cannot read my ID even my ID exist in my HTML code

Comment: Hi, It works for me. Is my careless mistake forget to put semicolon. Thanks a lot. You help me